# Trying to clone Diaspora and getting a segmentation fault error. What does that mean?

Tags: git

Sorry for sounding naive. I've never seen this before.

> Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/macuser/Sites/diaspora/.git/
>   got 3a266732986114800f58783337c85d6202dab81f
>   walk 3a266732986114800f58783337c85d6202dab81f
>   Getting alternates list for https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora.git
>   Also look at https://github.com/network/911765.git/
>   Getting pack list for https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora.git
>   Segmentation fault

Why/what is a segmentation fault?

Comment: Try doing `git clone git://github.com/diaspora/diaspora.git`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a seg fault occurs when the computer tries to access a piece of memory for which the computer doesn't have access. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault

Its usually a bug with the software that is directly interfacing with the computer, *e.g.* a seg fault found in Ruby is usually with respect to the interpreter, not the ruby code itself. If it is occurring frequently, I'd try updating your git install and if you still are getting it, I'd report it to the git core team.

Comment: @Trip: I can't reproduce this, and it's possible it'd go away with a newer version of git. (The output of yours looks like an older version.) If the problem persists in current git, and you report it, it'd be best if you could at least include a backtrace, and be ready to potentially provide some more debugging information.